# “500 - Internal server error” when calling ASP .Net Core 2.1.7 micro-service on Windows Server

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, iis-10

I have ASP.Net Core based micro-service, which is deployed on IIS10 running Windows 10 enterprise.

[image]
This application running all fine in all lower environments (Dev, QA) the moment i try to test it in UAT it start throwing

[image]

I validated the logs and  it says 500 nothing else. Inside IIS logs it says 500 0 0 nothing else.

I tried enabling Details Logs, tried running in Development mode as below still no details getting printed :( I even tried it running from Command prompt same limited error 500.

Application internally call another service which is also running on same machine and when I hit that standalone that is working.
This is exact same code and configs working fine in QA.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
     <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
   </handlers>
   <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Communications.Api.dll" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" stdoutLogEnabled="true" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
     <environmentVariables>
           <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
     </environmentVariables>
    <handlerSettings>
        <handlerSetting name="debugLevel" value="file" />
        <handlerSetting name="debugFile" value="D:\Communications\logs\ancm.log" />
 </handlerSettings>
   </aspNetCore>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="700000000" />
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
 </system.webServer>
     <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off" />
       <compilation debug="true" />
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How to get details to know real issue :(  Please guide.

Comment: Stop sharing screen shots. Why cannot you cut and paste the actual text here? Also what's written in `.\logs\stdout` file?

Comment: If text help you here it is: 

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
     Request finished in 42622.185ms 500 application/json

Comment: The error most likely will be in stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"

Comment: I got a hint after doing this, I Ran those calls from Localhost and looks like LB Url is not accessible on the machine itself hence it was timing out. because main service was calling other services using that LoadBalancer URL which is not working on same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Solution for this issue.

There is some configuration difference between QA and UAT.

The moment I changed URLs to localhost, it started working.